# Slowness of Talend version 8.0.1

Tags: talend

We have been facing issue with Talend open studio 8.0.1 version. It is very slow in the AWS instance Linux centos and the hardware configurations are mentioned below;

Environment : Linux AWS VM

OS : CentOS 7

RAM : 32 GB

CPU : 8 Core

HDD : 80 GB

We don't have any Anti-Virus software's running in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit .ini file associated with your studio executable.
You can upgrade xms and xmx values , which are quite low by default.